# CoffeeScript Wrapping Block Header Comment in Closure

Tags: coffeescript

I have the following CS snippet:

```
###
jQuery Observer
Copyright 2011 All Rights Reserved
###

$ = jQuery
...
```

Which compiles to:

```
(function() {
  /*
  jQuery Observer
  Copyright 2011 All Rights Reserved
  */
  var $;
  $ = jQuery;
  ...
}).call(this);
```

However, I'd like the header comment to appear at the top of the file (not inside the closure). Is this settable within CS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's currently no way to do this, but there is an open pull request which looks promising: https://github.com/jashkenas/coffee-script/pull/1684